# check if value exist in db and return other value if exist

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to generate random code , and insert into database
i want to generate other random code if exist in database

this my random class :

```
    <?php
class code {
    public $code;
    public function mycode(){

        $this->code = rand(1111111,9999999); //7894564

        $this->code = str_replace(0,"A",$this->code);
        $this->code = str_replace(1,"B",$this->code);
        $this->code = str_replace(2,"-",$this->code);
        $this->code = str_replace(3,"C",$this->code);
        $this->code = str_replace(4,"I",$this->code);
        $this->code = str_replace(5,"GB",$this->code);
        $this->code = str_replace(6,"7",$this->code);
        $this->code = str_replace(7,"W4",$this->code);
        $this->code = str_replace(8,"S",$this->code);
        $this->code = str_replace(9,"M",$this->code);
        $this->code = str_replace(10,"RQ",$this->code);

        $this->code = substr($this->code,0,9);

        return $this->code;

    }
}

$class_code = new code();
?>
```

here check & print code

```
 $code = $class_code->mycode(); 
    $get_code =  mysqli_query($link,"Select * from links WHERE link = '".$code."'");
    $if_exist = mysqli_num_rows($get_code);
                          if($if_exist == 1)
    {
          while($if_exist == 1)
          {
              // Here Return New Code
          }
    } else{
    echo $code;
                }
```

Comment: You forgot the part where you describe a problem.  In what way is this not working?

Comment: while loop check if code is exist in database , i want class generate other code if exist and print code

Comment: And what exactly is stopping you from doing that?  What's the actual problem?

Comment: Echo code.mycode(); wheres the problem???

Comment: while($if_exist == 1)
          {
              // Here i want the class generate new code
          }

Comment: Maybe he actually wants to check the database in the while loop? I.e. `$row = mysli_fetch_assoc()` as the while loop argument? This is a really bad question. The current while loop will be never ending by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below snippet. You will able to create unique random code using it. If you have any query please let me know.

```
<?php 
class code {
    public $code;
    public function mycode($link,$length=6){
        //Generating random code
        $characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
        $this->code = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $this->code .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
        }
        //Check generated code is exist in Db or not
        $get_code =  mysqli_query($link,"Select * from links WHERE link = '".$this->code."'");
        $if_exist = mysqli_num_rows($get_code);
        if($if_exist == 1)
        {
            //if code is already exist then recursively call function to generate new unique code.
            $this->mycode($link);
        }
        return $this->code;
    }
}
//create object
$class_code = new code();
//call function to generate unique code.
//$link is the connection
$uniqueCode = $class_code->mycode($link);
?>
```